# KerasRL: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-rl

In Python 3.10.10, I am trying to follow the CartPole example for KerasRL from https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl, but when I do so I receive the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'
```

By running the source code in "dqn_cartpole.py" line by line, I found that the import

```
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
```

triggers this error.

I have tried replacing KerasRL with KerasRL2, but doing this yields another error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'tensorflow.keras'
```

I have no idea why this error is occurring, but I assume there is a problem with the installation of KerasRL despite the fact that I followed the official documentation. Any assistance?

Comment: I am fairly certain that you cannot do it with Python 3.10. Try with 3.6-3.9 for the original KerasRL.